# Ability to automatically send a push notification when user approaches destination

Tags: api, geolocation, location, maps, sms

I am wanting to learn about information on what I need to do in my code to allow my app to send automatic txts to the user when they are a certain distance from a certain location.

FOR EXAMPLE: User is driving and is 1.0 miles away from a desired destination so the app will send a txt msg to the user notifying them of that information. "hello, you are approaching your favorite donut shop in 1 mile."

Comment: Do you have a code issue you want to fix? What language are you using? Maybe show some code..? etc. etc.

Comment: Here is my github. https://github.com/Csayegh123/Project1 Its nothing great. My goal is to make this an app.  I have no code issue I want to fix. Just someone to push me in the right direction on how to approach building an app that sends txts to the user.

Comment: You will need a map SDK API (Try Mapbox or Google Maps) and a SMS sending API. You will need to hook the SMS api dynamically into your app, so your code will need to be dynamic.

Comment: @JamesWalker that's exactly what I needed. I'll respond here if I have any more questions.